# Correct way to update map data type with cqerl

Tags: erlang, cql

I am having hard time coming with the syntax of updating map using cqerl. I have tried the following till now and it doesn't work

```
statement = "UPDATE keyspace SET data[?] = :data_value WHERE scope = ?;",
    values = [{data,"Key Value"},{data_value, "Data Value",{scope, "Scope Value"}]
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Also setting ttl does not work

```
statement = "INSERT INTO data(scope)
         VALUES(?) USING ttl ?",
    values = [{scope, "Scope Value"},{[ttl], 3650}]
```

Anyone, any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on reply from the contributor on github, it takes an atom, so '[ttl]' is the right way
https://github.com/matehat/cqerl/issues/122

For updating a map correct way is with atom in the values part

```
statement = "UPDATE keyspace SET data[?] = ? WHERE scope = ?;",
    values = [{'key(data)',"Key Value"},{'value(data)', "Data Value",{scope, "Scope Value"}]
```

Comment: you should add the link on this reply.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that you are using single quotes around the values, which in Erlang syntax indicates you are using [atoms.](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/data_types.html#id67942) Based on the documentation cqerl, it doesn't expect atoms there. [cqerl data types](https://github.com/matehat/cqerl#data-types)

For example try:

```
statement = "INSERT INTO data(scope)
     VALUES(?) USING ttl ?",
values = [{scope, "Scope Value"},{[ttl], 3650}]
```

Comment: Thanks for replying back, I did not meant single quote, I corrected above. I guess you have not tried running the code above, it does not work. I already tried this. I get this no match of right hand value {error,{throw,{{missing_parameter,{parameter,'[ttl]'},